# I am trying to upload my APK into the Playstore but it is not working... :(

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

I am trying to upload my app to the playstore but when I upload the APk this error appears, "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle file that was signed in debug mode. You must sign your APK or Android App Bundle in launch mode." I am not sure what to put in the com.company.name thing, or if that is the problem or not.

I did the app using Unity and I am not sure if maybe I did a mistake when I was building into the APK. This is the first app that I publish an APP and it is for a school project. Any help on the subject would be great.

Comment: Debug key is not needed for publish an app, you need a release key.

Answer (score 1):

In Android, you create something called a KeyStore.  Android Studio creates a debug KeyStore by default, and most people don't even think about it.  However, if you want to 'Release' your app to the public, you need to 'sign' it with a 'Release KeyStore'.  So, Google how to create a Release KeyStore, and do that first.  Then, when building your app for release, at least in Android Studio, you would go to Build/Generate Signed Bundle/APK.  Then, you would select your Release KeyStore and enter the passwords and alias.  This will then sign your app for Release, and you'll be able to upload it to the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign your app with a unique key. You can read more about it here - https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Here you can see how to sign your app in Unity: https://answers.unity.com/questions/326812/signing-android-application.html?childToView=600281#answer-600281